# Emoji across excel version

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, fonts, emoji

I am making an data entry form. For each row I made a data validation cell at the end for user to finalize the row. There are 4 possible action/values:

- blank: nothing
- ✔: the row is finalized
- ❌: delete the row
- : edit the row.
  The problem is with the 4th emoji (crayon). In excel version 2010 it just appear as a question block in the dropdown list from data validation. They all appear fine in Window + . listing.

As far as research go, I get that the font in data validation dropdown list is Tahoma, which is available in both computer. Some source say that it's the missing of Segoe UI Emoji font. I installed that, still doesn't fix it.

Is there a resource that have a list with emojis can appear correctly in which version of excel/windows?

Comment: This is wrongly closed. There is no "product, service, or learning material recommendations" involve in this question. This asks for documentation.